# Print amount of something in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to write a method that takes a number as an argument  and returns that number of stars on a single line  For example, an input of 5 returns: should return "*****" ALL ON THE SAME LINE

So far all I have is......

```
def stars()
   puts "#{"*"}"
end  
stars()
```

Comment: ...and you've tried? ...

Comment: The best thing you can do is fire up `irb`, the interactive ruby environment, and ***play***.  You might consider what happens if you type `'*' * 3`, for instance.

Comment: BTW, the interpolation is superfluous – `puts "#{"*"}"` is equivalent to `puts "*"`

Answer (score 2):

> Write a method that takes a number as an argument

Firstly, you have written a method, but at the moment it takes no argument, you need to fix it.

Other thing you need to know is that class String contains method [`#*`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-2A), where `#` means instance method. That means you can create multiples of any string you want.
Entering `'a' * 5` would return `'aaaaa'`.

Comment: You might want to add a link to the documentation for `String#*`

Answer (score 1):

#### Examples

Sometimes it's easier to learn by examples:

```
puts 'a' * 2 #=> aa
puts 'b' * 3 #=> bbb
puts 'c' * 5 #=> ccccc
```

So if you want `*`s printed, you write:

```
puts '*' * 7 #=> *******
```

#### Define a Method

To define a method that takes one argument:

```
def stars(n)
  puts n
end
```

To call this method:

```
stars(5)  #=> 5
stars(66) #=> 66
```

This should be enough knowledge for you to be able to construct your method as required. Also note, in Ruby we usually use two spaces for indentation.